# Python crashing when using error_bad_lines=False in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, macos, pandas, dataframe

Whenever I load data from a csv in a pandas dataframe and use :

```
error_bad_lines=False
```

it gives `Segmentation fault: 11` error and keeps crashing everytime.

Here it is..

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename,error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation Fault in Pandas read\_csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608868/segmentation-fault-in-pandas-read-csv)

Comment: what are your pandas, numpy and python versions?

Comment: i tested this line of code on a csv file and it worked like a charm, can you show here an example of your csv?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham my python version is 2.8, pandas .15.2 and numpy is 1.8.0rc1

Comment: @omri_saadon yeah sure..
here is the link and it got NULL entries too
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtbvwtj1eskl549/input.csv?dl=0)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that's 2.7.8^

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem fixed. Somehow the file format got changed and it was not parsing it properly because of which it crashed.

Sorry guys